# Horizontal Fragmentation in Oracle 10g Xpress Edition

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to do horizontal fragmentation of a table say employee. But fragmentation is often related to distributed databases.

How can I do this on my single home computer?

Could anyone list out the steps that should be performed? I saw the concept of link but really failed to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to horizontal fragmentation (distribution of rows depending on criteria into separate storage areas) would be the [Partitioning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/index.html) option in Oracle. This is a paid-for option and is not available in either Oracle 10g XE or 11g XE.